# PhantomJS screenshot always blank

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have PhantomJS installed and example scripts from [the official Phantom website](http://phantomjs.org) are working fine.

I'm trying to get [this screenshot example](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) to work:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

but all I keep getting is a blank github.png file weighing 582Kb

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you upload the png file somewhere? If it's that large, it probably is not blank.

Comment: Maybe the URL needs to be `https://github.com/`, since GitHub is now served securely.

Comment: To head off such guesses, I just tried this exact code with the latest PhantomJS, and it works fine for me.

Comment: What is your PhantomJS version, Liam?

Comment: apologies for the long delay in reply :(   phihag: you're right, it's an invisible 400x300px png file. Here is a copy: https://expirebox.com/download/aceff294d66decb2094ac6c622d0cfc6.html. Andy: I tried the https and is still produces the same file. Vaviloff: version 2.1.1

Comment: having the same issue with non https site

Answer (score 2):

**@ced-b**'s suggestion is wise, but I do not think your problem will be solved using a timeout because the real issue is most likely with SSL/TLS. GitHub is an HTTPS website. So if you want to get your screenshot, you may need to add the `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` option when you run your PhantomJS script. By default, you should receive a narrow screenshot, but you can of course set a larger viewport:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080
};

page.open('https://github.com/', function () {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Badacadabra: tried adding --ignore-ssl-errors=true and still produces the same png just slightly bigger due to the larger dimensions.

Comment: This script is working fine on my computer (I am using the same PhantomJS version). What is your environment?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to wait for the page to actually load and render. Try adding a timeout:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
     page.render('github.png');
     phantom.exit();
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with this library: https://github.com/juliangruber/url-to-screenshot

setting the sslCertificatesPath('any') fixed the problem

```
new Screenshot('https://somerandomsite.com/')
  .width(320)
  .height(320)
  .sslCertificatesPath('any')
  .capture()
  .then(img => {
    // do stuff with img
  })
```